# Function acts different for same argument

Tags: c, function, types, arguments, double

The question's title is not very specific, I know but it's because I don't know what's going on with my C program.. I'm trying to calculate sin(x) using Taylor Polynomials (with radiant). First, I want to share my code:

```
#define TAYLOR_MAX 10

double sin(double x){

    int i;
    double sum=0, fact=1, xi=x;

    for(i=1; i<TAYLOR_MAX; i+=2){
        sum += x / fact;
        x *= xi * xi * (-1);
        fact *= i * (i-1);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Okay, when I call this function as:

```
sin(1.0)
```

It runs and produces correct answer: 0.8414709848

But when I call like this:

```
double p=1.0;
sin(p)
```

It gives: -nan

Why this is happening? How can I solve this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `fact *= i * (i-1);`: in the first iteration with `i == 1` `fact` will become 0 and then you have a division by 0

Comment: But it's giving the correct answer? I mean when i start from 1 it should give error for all type of arguments, right?

Comment: Welcome to the mysterious world of Undefined Behaviour -- anything might happen including that the program seems to work

Comment: Both give me the `nan`. Were you calling the library `sin` function on the first test? Rename the function.

Comment: Than the behavior is Compiler/Computer depended? Any other answers?

Comment: You shouldn't call your home-brew sine function `sin`; that's the name of the function in the math library. The compiler may know about such functions. I guess it tries to optimize `sin(1.0)` as a pure function called on a constant.

Comment: Oops. That's the case, I guess :) Thank you everyone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code with my compiler and what happens is that the first call `sin(1.0)` doesn't actually call your implementation of `sin()` but instead something else which returns a correct answer. The second call `sin(p)` executes your `sin()` function which returns `-nan`, so it does not work it seems.

Try renaming your `sin()` function into something else and you should see this as well.